# Custom static table cells in XCode storyboard?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitableview

We are trying to teach our designer to create simple iOS apps using storyboards.

One thing we can't figure out though is a straightforward way to have custom static table cells.

Static in the sense that he can add static info to the cells in storyboards (not loaded from a database or anything).

The problem we're having is we can't work out how to make a custom cell with a custom layout.

We can create a custom layout programatically. However, in the storyboard bit doesn't show up the layout (it shows the layout of a standard table cell). So we can't fill in the extra labels and images and such.

Can we make a custom cell so that it will show up in storyboard and let us make static cells out of it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a property when you select the table view in the storyboard and you have to change it from Dynamic to Static and then you add the extra labels and images there.

Comment: Hi there, I thought that this would be bad for memory management. If we created a custom UITableViewCell subclass then it could reuse those cells, rather than building a custom layout for each cell.

Comment: It can reuse the cells you build through the storyboard without a subclass.  You can set the identifier and reuse them.  Edit: Or you can even create a custom class, assign the cell to that custom class in interface builder and build it graphically right there.

Comment: Yes, @JustinPaulson is correct.  Set the identifier but add the UI elements the the cell in the interface builder.